# PsychoPy sending triggers on 64bit OS

Tags: python, triggers, 64-bit, psychopy

I have a problem with sending triggers for eeg recording using PsychoPy standalone v1.81.00 on a Win7 64bit OS. I followed the descriptions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/psychopy-users/trigger$2064/psychopy-users/hbIO2wHK1KU/uDUrjzRuXTQJ) and don't get any (more) errors. The triggers, however, don't show on the recording computer (Brainvision Recorder under Win7 32bit).

What I did:

1. Downloaded and installed the [InpOutBinaries_1500](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.highrez.co.uk%2FDownloads%2FInpOut32%2Fdefault.htm&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNE9AFk_wwRxeKrxFME8xBfQXErWIg) via InpOutBinaries_1500\Win32\InstallDriver.exe
2. Copied the other files (inpout32.dll, .h and .lib as well as vssver2.scc) to the working directory of my script
3. Tried sending trigger codes with `windll.inpout32.Out32(0x378, triggerCode)`

The trigger code doesn't show up in Brainvision Recorder but seems to be set correctly when calling `print str(windll.inpout32.Inp32(0x378))`.

Thanks for every piece of advice or idea!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I'm not entirely sure which step(s) actually cut the curve but I recommend the following:

**Download and install [LPT Test Utility](http://www.xlentelectronics.nl/LPTTest/LPTTestUtilx64r.htm) on your presentation computer.**

At first, this program installs the `inpout32.dll` automatically and correctly regardless if you use a 32 or 64 bit OS.
More over, it helps you to monitor and manipulate the pins of your parallel port. If using the standard addresses (`LPT1` through `LPT3`) doesn't work, select `LPTX` and enter your address manually ([see here where to get your parallel port address on a Windows PC](http://www.radiosky.com/skypipehelp/V2/parallel_port_configuration.html)). If the triggers don't show on your recording computer using this program, you have an issue that is not related to PsychoPy.

**If this fails**, (re-)install a parallel port driver. Using Windows 7 this should not be necessary but actually solved one major issue for me. If this still fails, probably the hardware components (parallel port plug / card, cable(s), sync box) are damaged.

**If the triggers work with the "LPT Test Utility" program but not using PsychoPy**, an individual troubleshooting dependent on your code is necessary. Of course, you need to insert the port address that worked with "LPT Test Utility" in your PsychoPy code.

```
from psychopy import core
from ctypes import windll

windll.inpout32.Out32(portaddress, triggerCode) #sends the trigger with triggerCode being an integer between 0 and 255
core.wait(0.05) #wait 50ms
windll.inpout32.Out32(portaddress, 0) #deletes the trigger i.e. resets the pins
```

Best wishes,

Mario

Comment: While the "LPT Test Utility" did not really work for me, it got me on the right track. [Parallel-Port-Tester](https://www.downtowndougbrown.com/2013/06/parallel-port-tester/) is a similar program, which pointed me to the correct LPT address to use.